# NSSplitView partly collapse

Tags: swift, cocoa, autolayout, nssplitview

I have a NSSplitView with two horizontal subviews. The left one is a NSOutlineView, the right a NSTableView. The left view has two constraints for the width: 1) >= 150 and 2) <= 200. So I have a minimum and a maximum width.

At `func splitView(splitView: NSSplitView, canCollapseSubview subview: NSView) -> Bool {` I return `true` for the left subview. This works, but completely hides the left view (as it should).

My target is, that instead of the normal way, the left view only collapse to, let's say 50px. Is there a way how I can reach this? I thought about coding sth. in `func splitView(splitView: NSSplitView, resizeSubviewsWithOldSize oldSize: NSSize)`, but this is not the right way when working with autolayout (I tried, but setting the frames of the subviews causes a reload of the NSTableView at every change of the Splitview divider (which causes, that the tableview looses every selection)).

Answer (score 0):

First, whatever you want to call that behavior, it's not what Cocoa calls collapsing the subview. So, stop thinking in terms of collapsing.

Second, you can't specify a minimum width constraint and then expect the system to ignore it. If you want the view to sometimes be only 50 points wide, you can't set a constraint that it be >= 150 points.

You can try implementing the delegate method `splitView(_:constrainSplitPosition:ofSubviewAt:)` to have the divider position "snap" to the 150-point limit and the 50-point limit. That is, it could allow any position >= 150 points. For a position between 100 and 150 points, it would adjust it to 150 points. For a position below 100 points, it would adjust it to 50 points.